# Android Layout: 1 imageview on fixed position and 2 imageviews fill up the remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have made a design that looks like this:

[image]

The problem is the creation of the little triangle that should point to the currently selected category. 
In essence, without background and stuff it looks like this:

[image]

Below the category texts, there is a transparent blue rectangle placed and to the right of it the 'pointer' should be made.
I imagined that this pointer is placed in a relative layout which contains the following imageview elements:

1. a transparent rectangle which fills the space from the top till imageview 2
2. the imageview containing the pointer. This is just a square image with the completely transparent pointer rectangle. Which has a fixed width and height and is position on a fixed/different location using the Top and Left margins.
3. a transparent rectangle which fills the space from 2 till the bottom

I tried creating this with the relative layout, but I can't get it to work. It seems like only 1 element with a variable height can be used at a time.
I also tried to use a vertical layout, but that didn't do it at all.

What is the best method to accomplish my design goal?

Comment: could you show us your current layout xml?

Comment: The current layout includes a lot of other views and it isn't working at the moment. It seems like only one view can be used to fill the rest of the parent view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 9patch png version of your image. This is an image where only certain areas can stretch. There is a tool in the android SDK [have a look](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).
(You need to make the area to the left of the arrow the only part that stretches).

Then use a frame layout with two Layouts inside; One for the bright blue background and one for the pointer. Eg:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width/height/ect...>

    <LinearLayout android:id="BlueBackground"
                  android:background="brightblue"
                  android:layout_width/height/ect.../>

    <LinearLayout android:id="Pointer"
                  android:background="pointer9patch"
                  android:layout_width/height/ect...>
    //The List
    </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to the pointer menu to only take up a certain portion of the screen you can use a horizontal linearlayout to split the screen in two:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width/height/ect...>

    <ImageView android:id="BlueBackground"
               android:layout_width/height/ect...>
    <LinearLayout android:id="HSplitLayout"
                  orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout android:id="Pointer"
                   android:layout_width/height/ect...>
        //The List
        </LinearLayout>

        <ContentOnRight...>

    </LinearLayout>


 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I will try the 9 patch tomorrow. It seems like this could do the trick.

Comment: @user1575009 awesome, remember to come back and accept if this works =)

Comment: Tried the 9 patch solution and it worked!
Thank you big time!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following.  Using the example below, you would have to manage the selected visibility of the pointer ImageView and the selected text color in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#669999"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Favourites"
                android:textColor="#33CCFF"
                android:textSize="42sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_text"
                android:background="@drawable/pointer"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Coffee"
                android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                android:textSize="42sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_text"
                android:background="@drawable/pointer" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Milk"
                android:textColor="#33CCFF"
                android:textSize="42sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_text"
                android:background="@drawable/pointer"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Instant"
                android:textColor="#33CCFF"
                android:textSize="42sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_text"
                android:background="@drawable/pointer"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:background="#33CCFF" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will look like the following :

[image: screen mockup]

There's only one image used in this layout.  That is the pointer.png which I whipped up for this example.

[image: pointer.png]